# soap ui retrieving value from json response using groovy script

Tags: json, soap, groovy, soapui

how can i get the sample id of a product for which status is 'available' from the json response using groovy script
 [
    {
        "sampleId": "17",
        "partNumber": "83729219",
        "sampleName": "Peter",
        "shortDescription": "Peter",
        "description": "Peter",
        "productUrl": "https://www.alwaysdis",
        "sampleImage": "http://sit1.author.gillette",
        "sku": null,
        "categoryId": 4,
        "parentSampleId": null,
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "variantName": "Pads Plus",
        "stockCount": 0,
        "noOfOrderPerCategory": 0,
        "noOfOrderPerSample": 0,
        "status": "NOT_AVAILABLE",
        "variants": []
    },
    {
        "sampleId": "27",
        "partNumber": "83729568",
        "sampleName": "ALWAYS DISCREET Incontinence Pants Normal",
        "shortDescription": null,
        "description": "\n

ALWAYS DISCREET Incontinence Pants for sensitive bladder. RapidDry an",
        "productUrl": "https://www.alwainence-pants/always-discreet-medium-incontinence-pants",
        "sampleImage": "/sitecore/media library/AlwaysDiscreet_UK/Im",
        "sku": null,
        "categoryId": 4,
        "parentSampleId": null,
        "locale": "en-GB",
        "variantName": " ",
        "stockCount": 79,
        "noOfOrderPerCategory": 0,
        "noOfOrderPerSample": 0,
        "status": "AVAILABLE",
        "variants": []
    }
]

how can i get the sample id of a product for which status is 'available' from the json response using groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONSlurper` to parse the String and then just use a `Closure` to filter the data, like this:

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(jsonData)
def availableSamples = result.findAll{it.status == 'AVAILABLE'}
```